# Payment gateway that accepts USD (credit card or paypal ... ) and provides the payment as a cryptocurrency

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, bitcoin, ethereum

Is there a payment gateway (API), that makes customers pay in USD and provides you the payment in a desired cryptocurrency, like Ripple?

Or is there an other way to collect payments on a website and convert them to CCs in an automated way via API calls or so ...

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't support this type of transfer. When you get the payment from your customers in USD, the amount will credit to your PayPal account balance. You will need to withdraw the PayPal account balance to a local bank account.